# How to check executable code signing signatures?

Tags: digital-signature, code-signing

How can I see *all* code signing signatures an executable has?
I know that requests for a tool are usually considered as opinion based, but I really can't find one and I don't expect many answers.

Background:

I have an executable that was signed by the vendor (for UAC purposes). The application was then tested by me and I apply my signature using Windows SDK 8 `signtool /as` (append signature).

I cannot see the certificate in Windows Explorer, although it says "certificate list".

`Signtool /verify` does not show the certificate (maybe because it reports an error for a not trusted certificate before).

I cannot get the certificate with C#, because the the class supports only one certificate (the first one). For the C# solution, I posted a [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547311/code-signing-an-executable-twice).

Googling for freeware, I could not find any tools which would display all certificates. Even the demo version of the commercial [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/pe-explorer-digital-signature.htm) doesn't show it.

**Update 2015-06-01**

[SysInternals Sigcheck](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx) (as proposed in an answer) shows only the first signature plus the certificate chain.

In the meanwhile, there must have been an update to Microsoft Windows. Windows Explorer now shows a list of certificates.

[image: Digital Signatures Windows Explorer]

Comment: i have found AnalyzePESig to be very useful. https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/authenticode-tools/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the free `osslsigncode` tool for this:
https://github.com/SummitRoute/osslsigncode-fork

> osslsigncode verify my.exe

UPDATE: The binary installed through [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io) using the command below is a better option (updated and non-Cygwin dependencies):

> pacman -S mingw-w64-{i686,x86_64}-osslsigncode

Comment: It seems that `osslsigncode` does not consider digital signature catalogs. It might also need an update, because on my PC it fails with `10896:error:21075076` which seems to be related to openssl [Bug 1526959](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1526959)